# What is a good icon for expressing sarcasm?

Tags: icon, symbolism

I created smiley for happy, sad and neutral event. Any suggestion for sarcasm?

Here is the image for above three expression:

[image: Happt]

[image: sad]

[image: neutral]

Can someone suggest an icon for sarcasm?

Comment: rolled eyes with a half-smile?

Comment: :-P ? It's available everywhere, at least.

Comment: related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony_punctuation There have been tries to propose a generally-understood sarcasm interpunction mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont see sarcasm in any icon provided.

By the wiki "Sarcasm is "a sharp, bitter, or cutting expression or remark; a bitter gibe or taunt."

I would use a tongue on the first image which smile I would change to a one similar to the image below - for me it is very sarcastic...

[image: sarcasm]

Comment: @Dominic yes, I agreee. Sarcasm is not a "simple" emotion which we can express and illustrate by lips and  eyes outline...

Answer (score 2):

To stay within your existing theme, I'd probably just use a slanted mouth.

[image]

Anything more would necessitate rethinking the other icons as well in order to add a bit more definition overall. I think the tongue out is a good idea, but using that for "sarcasm" would add a level of detail not present in the icons you already have.